# Proper syntax for including a ruby variable in an Ajax call inside a SLIM view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, slim-lang

```
Rails
Ajax
SLIM
```

I would like to use SLIM for my Rails views, but I can't figure out the syntax for using a Ruby variable inside an Ajax call.

If my view has an html.erb extension, I can put in it something like this:

```
<script>
  $('#MyDivId').replaceWith({
    ajax: '/users_activities?email=<%= @user.email%>'
  });
</script>
```

But, if this was a .html.slim view, if I do:

```
javascript:
  $('#MyDivId').replaceWith({
    ajax: '/users_activities?email=<%= @user.email%>'
  });
```

I would get an error message. Any idea what the proper syntax is for doing this in SLIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
'/users_activities?email=#{@user.email}'
```

Comment: Does string interpolation work with single quotes in slim? That would be surprising, but I don't use slim and don't know.

Comment: I will test this to confirm

Comment: @jvillian Sorry, I also meant to clarify that it does not work with single quotes, it needs double quotes

Comment: That's not ruby string interpolation, the string in my example is not a ruby string, it's a javascript string and the code inside #{ } is evaluated by the template processor. It doesn't even have to be inside a javascript string (if you have an integer in a ruby variable, you can do `let jsVar = #{rubyVar};` and it works).

Comment: https://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Text_interpolation (it doesn't care if `#{ }` is inside a string or not)